# Accessing HTML <textarea> data and store them as file

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

I have following task:
I need to gather information from multiple `<textarea>` tags, format them a bit and save on hard drive preferably in CSV format.

**Important note no. 1:** that data source HTML document is a file on my local hard drive, it's not hosted on any server (this file is a product of export from some database management tool).

**Important note no. 2:** only script language engine available is python

I already do some effort on preparing some python script that embed CSS stylesheet links and JavaScript links into this HTML file to use and some jQuery library functions for displaying purposes.

Now, on specific action (i.e. "save" button click) I need to:

- Search for filled `<textarea>` tags (jQuery job?)
- Format them and glue in single variable preferably (jQuery as well)
- Display "save as" dialogue
- Save file on hard drive

Well as far as I know, JavaScript is not allowed to manipulate files on machine file system, so for writing file this should be some server-side script, is that correct?

Should this save script be triggered by "save as" button? (realized as submit form button)? If yes,  can I run firstly some JavaScript function (gathering textarea data and format them) and later save this in file?

How this kind of data can be passed to this server-side script?

Thank you for all kind of help and advice.

EDIT:
I see that some users already point `<a>` tag with download attribute, but there is one additional issue: we have to assume IE as web browser, which by default does not support download attribute.

Comment: You only need JS and HTML for this. Use `<a download="something.csv">Save as…</a>` and set the `href` to a [`Blob` URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) where the `Blob` contains the CSV data formatted with JavaScript.

Comment: You can perform this with something like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3cb5wcz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer was posted as a comment instead of as an answer for some reason. Code courtesy of gabrielperales:

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
  function toCSV(text){
    var str= 'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,';
    str += btoa(text);
    return str;
  }

  $('#editor').on('change', function(){
    $('#download').attr('href', toCSV($(this).val()));
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
<br/>
<a id="download" href="" download="file.csv">Download</a>
```